I have an issue in my code and need helping fixing it
In this code I am using MIPS Assembly and I am trying to find the factorial of 3 using recursion. But my output is 4 when it should be 6. Here is my code below.
    .data
result_str:     .asciiz "Factorial of 3 = "
newline:        .asciiz "\n"

    .text
    .globl main

main:
    # Calculates the factorial of 3
    li $a0, 3
    jal factorial

    # Prints the result
    li $v0, 4        
    la $a0, result_str  
    syscall

    move $a0, $v0     
    li $v0, 1         
    syscall

    # Prints a newline
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    # Exits program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

factorial:
    # Save return address
    addi $sp, $sp, -8
    sw $ra, 4($sp)
    sw $s0, 0($sp)

    # if n <= 1 return 1
    li $t0, 1
    ble $a0, $t0, base_case

 
    addi $a0, $a0, -1   # save a0 to a new spot 
    jal factorial
    move $s0, $v0  

    # Multiply
    mul $v0, $a0, $s0  

    lw $ra, 4($sp)
    lw $s0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 8
    jr $ra

base_case:
    # If n <= 1 return 1
    li $v0, 1

    lw $ra, 4($sp)
    lw $s0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 8
    jr $ra

I am not sure what is wrong with it I think there is an error in the factorial section of the code.

You should not expect $a0 to survive a function call.
It is not a good use of $s0 to simply hold a copy of the return value from the recursive call.
The way to use $s0 is both before and after the call, since it survives a call (by compliance to the calling convention).
Initialize $s0 as a copy of $a0 before the recursive call (but after your function prologue).
Then use $s0 to multiply $v0 after the recursive call.
So, now $s0 is initialized before the call (and survives the call) and is used after.
Your prologue and epiloge are good as is.
